# Woocommerce API get all products

Tags: java, api, woocommerce, get

I tried to get product from API with some parameters. I used  [WooCommerce API Java Wrapper](https://github.com/icoderman/wc-api-java). REST API with OAuth 1.0. Simple getAll method return list of one page (10 products). To get all i must set how much products must be in one page and use offset. To get third page must send this parameters: "per_page=10&offset=20". I test with query in get&post programm - all work. In Java, when i added parameters - i got error (401)- "Invalid signature - the provided signature did not match".
I changed WooCommerceAPI class:

```
private static final String API_URL_FORMAT = "%s/wp-json/wc/v2/%s";
    private static final String API_URL_ONE_ENTITY_FORMAT = "%s/wp-json/wc/v2/%s/%d";
    private HttpClient client;
    private OAuthConfig config;
 public List getAll(String endpointBase) {
        String url = String.format(API_URL_FORMAT, config.getUrl(), endpointBase) + "?per_page=10&offset=20";
        String signature = OAuthSignature.getAsQueryString(config, url, HttpMethod.GET);
        String securedUrl = String.format("%s&%s", url, signature);
        System.out.println("url="+url);
        System.out.println("securedUrl="+securedUrl);
        return client.getAll(securedUrl);
    }
```

But I have got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just released a new version of wc-api-java library (version 1.2) and now you can use the method getAll with params argument where you can put additional request parameters. For example:

```
// Get all with request parameters
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("per_page","100");
params.put("offset","0");
List products = wooCommerce.getAll(EndpointBaseType.PRODUCTS.getValue(), params);

System.out.println(products.size());
```

Comment: @icorederman how can I extract product details like products.get(0).name or products.get(0).get("name")

Comment: @DaniyalJavaid products.get(0).get("name") should work, but you'll have to properly cast it, something like this ((List<Map<String, Object>>)products).get(0).get("name")

Comment: @DaniyalJavaid you can do List<Map<String, Object>> products = wooCommerce.getAll(EndpointBaseType.PRODUCTS.getValue(), params); Object name = products.get(0).get("name");

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, you changed URL_SECURED_FORMAT from `"%s?%s"` to `"%s&%s"`, as soon as you added query params. But problem is that signature is generated based on *all* query params, not only oauth_*, and your params `offset` and `per_page` are ignored while generating signature (as soon as lib author did not expect additional params).

Think that you need to modify this lib to support signature based on all params.

Comment: But I've put additional parameters into url. And url - came in into signature, isn't it?

Comment: I do not see extracting params from `endpoint` in `OAuthSignature`. And, as I said, based on string format for `URL_SECURED_FORMAT` (specially on question mark as delimiter), it does not look like parameters are expected by lib in endpoint url,

Comment: Hi, @Evgeny 's answer is correct, currently my library doesn't support any additional parameters. I'll try to find spare time to add this possibility soon. Thanks.