# WooCommerce API - Getting JsonParseException when reading data

Tags: java, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm making a program to obtain orders from a WordPress page.

In many test, the next code worked correctly:

```
        OAuthConfig config = new OAuthConfig(parameters.getUrl(), parameters.getConsumerKey(), parameters.getConsumerSecret());
        WooCommerce wooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI(config, ApiVersionType.V3);

        Map<String, String> parametersOrders = new HashMap<>();
        parametersOrders .put("per_page", "100");
        parametersOrders .put("offset", "0");

        List ordersCreated = wooCommerce.getAll(EndpointBaseType.ORDERS.getValue(), parametersOrders );
```

But now in production I'm getting the next error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@56c43543; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Apparently, I'm reading a *xml* object instead of a *json*.

How can I change that? It's something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT 1:**

The first time I've tried this, and it worked correctly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968854/4815994

The orders was retrieved successfully. Now I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was skipping the parameters part; I'm getting this data from a database:

```
WooCommerceParameters parameters= GetWooCommerceParameters();

OAuthConfig config = new OAuthConfig(parameters.getUrl(), parameters.getConsumerKey(), parameters.getConsumerSecret());
```

The consumer key and the consumer secret is ok, but the URL have this format:

```
'https://test.com/store/'
```

And must be like this:

```
'https://test.com/store'
```

Without the final slash